# setTimeout show blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, google-visualization

I try to put a chart in my website and when I define a setTimeout in my function, show me a blank page and I don´t why. If I create a table with my hand, it´s works fine, but if I create my table using the function in `main.js` that´s get the information in my web service, doesn´t work and show after one second(time that I defined) a blank page.

here my code:
inde.html

```
<div style="width:700px;height:500px;margin-top:20px;margin-top:200px;">
        <table id="chartdiv">

            </table>

        </div>

...

<script type="text/javascript" src="../front-end/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../front-end/js/jquery.gvChart-0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function coisocoiso(){
        setTimeout(function() {
        gvChartInit();
        jQuery1(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery('#chartdiv').gvChart({
                chartType: 'PieChart',
                gvSettings: {
                    vAxis: {title: 'No of Visitors'},
                    hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
                    width: 720,
                    height: 300,
                    }
            });
        });
}, 1000);
}
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){



    $("#jogador").hide()
    $("#selecoes").hide();
    $("#jogoss").hide();
    $("#selecaoList").click(function () {
        $("#index").hide();
        $("#selecoes").show();
        coiso();
        coisocoiso();

        });

    $("#tagList").click(function () {
        $("#index").hide();
        $("#selecoes").show();
        coiso();
        coisocoiso();

    });
```

main.js

```
function addChart(data) {
    // JAX-RS serializes an empty list as null, and a 'collection of one' as an object (not an 'array of one')
    var list = data == null ? [] : (data.pessoa instanceof Array ? data.pessoa : [data.pessoa]);



     $('#chartdiv').empty();
    var tr = $( '<tr/>' ),
        thead = $( '<thead/>' ),
        caption = $( '<caption/>' ),
        tbody = $( '<tbody/>' ),
        th = $( '<th/>' ),
        td = $( '<td/>' ),
        row;

$('#chartdiv').append( caption.clone('Coiso') );

    row = thead.clone();
    var row1;
    row1 = tr.clone();
    row1.append(th.clone().html(''));

    $.each(list, function(index, pessoa) {
        row1.append( th.clone().html(pessoa.nome));
    });
    row.append(row1);
    $('#chartdiv').append( row );


    var coiso = 0;
    var totalClicks = parseInt(coiso,10);

    $.each(list, function(index, pessoa) {
            totalClicks = parseInt(totalClicks,10) + parseInt(pessoa.clicks,10);
    });


    var row2,row3;


    row2 = tbody.clone();
    row3 = tr.clone();
    row3.append(th.clone().html(parseInt(totalClicks,10)));


    $.each(list, function(index, pessoa) {
            row3.append( td.clone().html(pessoa.clicks));
    });

    row2.append(row3);
    $('#chartdiv').append(row2);

}
```

Comment: Try remove that coma after `height: 300,` in `gvSettings:`

Comment: I guess you need to pass reference of object in setTimeout using bind().

Comment: Ranjan Kumar I don´t I understand very well your solution, can you explain again please

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that your document ready event fires before you create the document ready handler.  Why are you using `setTimeout`?  When using the Visualization API, your chart code should run from within a callback from the google loader.